# Put html formatted text in tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip

Is it possible and how to display in a tooltip a formatted HTML content? I was looking for a similar question in the forum but didn't find exactly what i need. I have made a simple example to clear up my question:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.tooltip').tooltipster();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Example<sup class="tooltip" title="***">[1]</sup>
    <span id="ttp">This is a<b>custom bold text</b></span>
</body>
```

The question is how the text with `id="ttp"` to be displayed in the **"title"** . Will be grateful for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how dynamic you want it and your html struture but there is an option to provide content.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
                content: $('#ttp').html()
            });
        });
    </script>
```

but if your structure is dynamic then on [FunctionInit][1] you can set the content from element you want. Here I find sibling span with id ttp and get it's html and set that as content. Note: setTimeout is required here, as tooltip should be initialzied before you set new content(async simulation).

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
        content: 'Empty title',
        contentAsHTML: true,
        functionInit: function(origin, content) {
            var newTip = $(this).siblings('#ttp').html();
            setTimeout(function(){ origin.tooltipster('content', newTip);},50);
        }
    });
});
```

[1]:

Comment: and what should be there in the **title** field in the **body** part?

Comment: Which body part? your mean title attribute? leave it empty.